# how to convert url to friendly url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I hava a php script for manage ads but i want to use friendly url for it.

please give me htaccess code for all this examples:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?page/login
to
mydomain.com/login
```

```
mydomain.com/index.php?page=register&step=2
to
mydomain.com/register/step-2/
```

```
mydomain.com/index.php?page=articles&category=countries&article=afghanistan
to
mydomain.com/articles/countries/afghanistan
```

Comment: Did you search in https://google.com?

Comment: Check out this website: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :(it won't be dynamic)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /login/(.*)$ /index.php?page/login
RewriteRule /register/step-2/(.*)$ /index.php?page=register&step=2
RewriteRule /articles/countries/afghanistan/(.*)$ /index.php?page=articles&category=countries&article=afghanistan
```

This is short use and must minimal.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to create a file index.php manaja requested urls

```
// .htaccess
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and index.php

```
$url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$url = explode('/', $url);
```

example if user call url //localhost/login

```
// you include the file if exists
include('rout to file/'.$url[0].'.php');
```